# Stop looping of jssor slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jssor

I want to stop the looping of jssor slider here is my code, I want to stop the slider at the end and start

```
var transitions = [{
   $Duration: 1200, x: 0.3, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7] },                                                                                                     
   $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear}, $Opacity: 2}
];
var options = {
    $AutoPlay: false,
    $SlideWidth: 75,
    $SlideHeight: 75,
    $SlideshowOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
        $Transitions: transitions,
        $TransitionsOrder: 1,
    },
    $Cols: 5,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

just add to options $Loop:0 (or 2 to rewind)
http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html

```
var transitions = [{
   $Duration: 1200, x: 0.3, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7] },                                                                                                     
   $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear}, $Opacity: 2}
];
var options = {
    $AutoPlay: false,
    $SlideWidth: 75,
    $SlideHeight: 75,
    $SlideshowOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
        $Transitions: transitions,
        $TransitionsOrder: 1,
    },
    $Cols: 5,
    $Loop:0
};
```